# Why do we need std::boolean and what is the use of it?

Tags: c++, boolean, std, c++20

Since we already have true and false as the type `bool` in C++, why do we need the class std::boolean and what's the use of it? Useful links also appreciated.

Comment: Where do you found std::boolean?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're referring to. But there is a proposal [here](https://std-proposals.isocpp.narkive.com/Q71Crq1U/c-types-std-boolean-std-true-std-false-and-std-bool-intermediate) for std::boolean. Which at-least in the first part, is arguing that it would allow for a more oop approach to handling if else situations than if else. The example they give is a bool type could be made to invoke a function based on whether it's true, false or intermediate after being set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The mystery of C++20 concept boolean-testable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66938439/the-mystery-of-c20-concept-boolean-testable)

Comment: The website you have linked is about Alore, not C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::boolean` used to be a part of the C++20 draft standard (e.g. it can be found in [N4835](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/main/papers/n4835.pdf)), but in the actual C++20 standard it is replaced by an exposition-only concept [`boolean-testable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/boolean-testable). The change happened around February 2020 as a result of adoption of [P1964R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1964r2.html) .

In either incarnation it is a concept, not a type. That is, a template that says whether its argument type can be used as a boolean. `bool` obviously can be used this way, but not only: integral types, pointer types, and any class that defines a conversion to `bool` and/or overloads boolean operators like `!` and `&&` also qualify.